# Extend/subclass numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, subclassing

How do I extend/subclass numpy .. I'm looking at the docs, but some things are still unclear.

I want to create a class which extends numpy array and have the following properties :

1. Act as numpy array
2. Add additional object attributes
3. Override + and * ops, but add method calls that allow me to access the original capabilities
4. how can I update the array inside a method. F.e.

   ```
   class MyNP:  

     def __init__(self, val, a1):
        self.attr1 = a1
        self = val  #update/assign val

     def __add__(self,right): ....
     def add(self,right): super....
   ```

this wont work cause it would overwrite the self and it will become numpy instead of MyNP.

5. Override **repr**, simply defining it will work, right?
6. copy() method. I currently do it like this :

   ```
   def copy(self): return type(self)(vsize=self.vsize, vsn=self.bits)
   ```
7. How to force ops like np.sort(), np.concatenate(), np.unique() to return MyNP when they have MyNP operands ?

---

Comment: Overwriting the local variable `self` in a function does absolutely nothing. Did you mean `self[...] = val`? By the time you are in `__init__`, the array has already been created and you can't replace external references to it or change the buffer size.

Comment: u mean  self[:] = val ?

Comment: No, I mean `self[...]`. The ellipsis is equivalent to repeating `:` as many times as necessary. Not all your arrays will be 1-D. `[:]` may work too, but `[...]` is safer and probably more correct.

Comment: You need to override `__new__`, not `__init__`. Start by reading https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.subclassing.html

Comment: Here's half of what you're looking for: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.subclassing.html#simple-example-adding-an-extra-attribute-to-ndarray

Comment: subclassing `ndarray` is much more work than with the usual Python class.  `np.matrix` and `np.ma.MaskedArray` are the only widely used subclasses that `numpy` provides.  Their source files will give you an idea of how much work is required.

Comment: __new__ so far is working /it was abit hard to do it/, still some problems with .copy() and .sort() and probably with other inplace ops

Comment: `x[...]` is indeed safer than `x[:]`, because it handles 0-dimensional arrays correctly.